Maximum excursion in applying Bézout
Suppose that we are given positive integers $n,m$.
We know from Bézout's theorem, that if we start from $0$ we can reach $\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)$ by moving up and down the integer number line in increments of $\pm m$ and $\pm n$.
In particular, it is possible to do this without ever going below $0$.
My question is the following. As a function of $n$ and $m$, what is the minimum distance from $0$ that must be achieved by such a 'walk' from $0$ to $\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)$ under the condition that we never go below $0$?
My thoughts are the following.
It is only worth considering the case $\mathrm{gcd}(n,m) < n,m$.
It seems clear to me that we can bound the required quantity by $n+m$ (strategy: we can write WLOG $a \cdot n - b \cdot m = \mathrm{gcd}(n,m) $ for $a,b \in \mathbb N$, so we can get to the required endpoint by adding $a$ instances of $n$ and subtracting $b$ instances $m$ in some order, so at any stage, before the next $n$ is added, if our current position is $\>\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)$, there must be enough $m$'s left to be subtracted for it to be possible to at least reduce what is left modulo $m$ before we add another $n$.)

You want the minimum value of $|x|+|y|$ over all integer solutions $x,y$ of $mx+ny=\gcd(m,n).$You can always find a solution with $|x|+|y|<\frac{m+n}{\gcd(m,n)}-2.$ You can probably do better for an upper bound.

@ThomasAndrews In the case $n=6$ and $m=7$, the minimum distance from $0$ reached is at least $6$. However $(x,y)=(-1,1)$  gives a solution with $|x|+|y|=2$? I do not see why this quantity is the same as the one I am interested in.

Why isn't $0,7,7-6=1$ a suitable path?

So, are you trying to minimize $\max_k {mx_k + ny_k}$ over all sequences $(x_k, y_k)$, $k = 0, \ldots, K$, where $mx_k + ny_k \geq 0$ for all $k$, $x_0 = 0, y_0 = 0$, $mx_K + ny_K = GCD(m,n)$,
and
$(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1}) - (x_k, y_k) \in {(0, \pm 1), (\pm 1, 0)}$ for all $k>0$ ?

@JairTaylor Yes, precisely.

@ThomasAndrews It is a suitable path. My point is that the first message seems to imply that you are claiming that the answer to my question is the minimum value of $|x|+|y|$ over solutions to the Bézout equation, however for this pair of $n,m$, the former is $≥6$ but the latter is $≤2$.
